# Image not showing up in iOS simulator

Tags: xcode

I am currently working on an app in Xcode. I'm having the following problem:
I have created a 60-60 pixel image in Adobe Photoshop with a transparant background. I saved this as an .png file, and added it to the 'Supporting Files' section of Xcode. I created an image view in my Main.storyboard. However, when I run the iOS Simulator, the image doesn't appear. I have tried the same thing with a different .png file that wasn't made with Adobe Photoshop, and this image did appear in the iOS Simulator, so the problem clearly has to do with the image and not with the positioning or coding.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: As long as you use png. It does matter where you created it will work on iOS. Did you try manually set imageView's image by interface builder?

Comment: Yes I have. The image still doesn't show up in the iOS Simulator.

Comment: So when you set from interface builder it looks good but when you run it disappear on simulator? Do you image setting code in your controller? You may remove the image from interface builder, clean project then add your image manually from interface builder and delete your code from controller if you have any. Make sure if you have size classes enabled you added image the size you are testing against.

Comment: That's right. I just found out that there's an error that pops up when I open the iOS simulator. It says: 2014-11-19 17:20:27.149 Virety[1288:37946] Could not load the "newcharacter.png" image referenced from a nib in the bundle with identifier "Young-Webdevelopment.Virety". Maybe it's due something with this?

Comment: yes if it cannot load the image it cannot show. Try what i suggested in previous post.